# Scale multiple containers of a service in a single host

Tags: performance, docker, docker-compose, scale, docker-swarm

I am scaling multiple containers of a service on a single linux host by command "docker-compose up --scale". However, each container can use all the resources (CPU and RAM) of the host. It seems to be useless to scale like that.

Thus, I try to limit availabe CPU and RAM for each container (I am currently using docker-compose version 2) by "cpus" and "mem_limit" tag in docker-compose.yml file.

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  test:
    image: test
    mem_limit: 500000000
    container_name: test
    build: ./test
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 500000000
    mem_reservation: 300m
    cpus: 0.5
    networks:
      - test-network
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
```

But I don't know that if it is useful to scale multiple containers of a service on a single host? Also, is there any ways to automatically scale this service (scale on demand)?
Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: test
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 500M
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
    networks:
      - test-network
networks:
  test-network:
```

```
docker swarm init #Initialize machine as docker swarm manager
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml testing #This will start 5 containers for the same image as replica
```

You can scale the app by changing the replicas to 6 value in docker-compose.yml, saving the change, and re-running

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml testing #Docker performs an in-place update, no need to tear the stack down first or kill any containers
```

For detailed explanation you can follow this article, https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/.
But i suggest you to start with first part of this tutorial.

And for any docker experiments you can try https://labs.play-with-docker.com/

Comment: whoever marked this answer as negative, please tell the reason

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I realized that it seems to be useless to scale multiple containers on a single host (even when I limit resource for each container, I think it's not the right way to scale), so I decided to try kubernetes to deploy on several hosts